# Problem when using a while loop for data verification

Tags: java, while-loop

I have declared scanner, start

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Type the word \"Start\" when your ready to begin the quiz");
start = input.nextLine();
input.nextLine();
while(!start.equals("start")){
  System.out.println("Make sure you read the question and try again");
  start = input.nextLine();
}
```

I expected to enter "start" and the while loop will exit but instead i have to enter "start" twice to exit the while loop

Comment: You're calling `input.nextLine()` **TWICE** before your loop.  Get rid of the line that is `input.nextLine();` by itself.

Comment: Consider converting to all lower or upper case before doing the comparison.

Comment: if i get rid of input.nextLine(); there wouldn't even be a box where the user can enter a value

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `do - while` loop. It is different from `while` loop because it first executes the code and then it evaluates the condition that is set in while statement.

```
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Type the word \"start\" when your ready to begin the quiz");
    String start, answer;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        start = input.nextLine();
        if(!start.equals("start")) {
            System.out.println("Make sure you read the question and try again");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter the answer here: ");
            answer = input.nextLine();
        }
    } while (!start.equals("start"));
```

Comment: i need the input.nextLine(); for the user to enter some value. If i only have the start = input.nextLine(); there wouldnt be a box for the user to enter

Comment: I put it again :)

Comment: so does it work for you or do you have to enter start twice

Comment: I only enter start once. :) As I executed the code, your input.nextLine() is asking the user to enter something, but nothing is saved :(.

Comment: I think that is because i asked for user input  before this one

Comment: I edited the answer for your purpose! :) See it and tell me if that is what you are looking for :)

Comment: i tried your edit but the user does no get the option to enter start, it just output: Type the word \"start\" when your ready to begin the quiz and Make sure you read the question and try again